# Creating watermark tracking pubsub subscription failure after applying withTimestampAttribute to PubsubIO

Tags: google-cloud-dataflow, apache-beam, google-cloud-pubsub

In Google Dataflow streaming, I want to use record timestamps provided in Pub/Sub message attributes rather than the published timestamp.

```
PubsubIO.Read<T> pubsubIO = PubsubIO.readProtos(type).fromSubscription(options.getPubSubSubscription())
pubsubIO.withTimestampAttribute("eventTimestamp");
```

When I added `withTimestampAttribute` to the code, it worked fine with local direct runner, but failed when using Google Cloud Dataflow Runner.

`Workflow failed. Causes: Step setup_resource_/subscriptions/xxxxxx: Set up of resource /subscriptions/xxxxxx failed, Creating watermark tracking pubsub subscription projects/xxxxxx to topic projects/xxxxxx failed with error: User not authorized to perform this action.`

The service account to run dataflow have admin roles on dataflow, pubsub, etc, so I assume we can rule out the IAM issue.

Not sure if I missed any required configurations, e.g extra setup when create the pub/sub topic and subscription?

Answer (score 0):

The problem has been resolved after I added Pub/Sub Subscriber role to the service account. So it is the IAM issue...

Looks like the Dataflow is creating a subscription on the fly when it runs, that's why only admin role on resources level(topic/subscription) was not enough, it needs to add on service account IAM.